# SQL select from table and get table name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have like three tables which have some same columns like ID, Name, Image, ...
I am selecting from them using this code

```
(SELECT ID, Name FROM `creatures` WHERE ... )
UNION
(SELECT ID, Name FROM `items` ...)
UNION
( ... FROM `anothertable` ... )
```

Im doing this in php which creates a row to a table for each result. Now the problem is, I need to know from which table the row was taken. Im new to SQL and I dont know if it even can be done somehow. I though about something like:

```
SELECT ID, Name, TableName FROM ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: As some of the answers point out, the `UNION ALL` set operator is more efficient than the `UNION` set operator, because it doesn't incur the overhead of sorting the result set to identify and remove duplicate rows before they are returned.

Comment: ok, Im definitely gonna use it :) thank you all for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the table name as a string literal to each query:

```
(SELECT 'creatures' AS table_name, ID, Name FROM `creatures` WHERE ... )
UNION
(SELECT 'items' AS table_name, ID, Name FROM `items` ...)
UNION
( ... FROM `anothertable` ... )
```

**EDIT:**
Notice that since you know that two rows from different tables cannot be equal, you can now use `union all` instead of `union`, which may give you a slight performance boost.

Answer (score 3):

You can just add a column indiciating the table name to the selects;

```
(SELECT 'creatures' AS tablename, ID, Name FROM `creatures` WHERE ... )
UNION
(SELECT 'items' AS tablename, ID, Name FROM `items` ...)
UNION
( ... FROM `anothertable` ... )
```

A side note, since you want *all* rows, using `UNION ALL` is faster since it does not need to perform a `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(SELECT ID, Name, 'creatures' as TableName FROM `creatures` WHERE ... )
UNION ALL
(SELECT ID, Name, 'items' as TableName FROM `items` ...)
UNION All
( SELECT ID, Name, 'anothertable' as TableName FROM `anothertable` ... )
```

**Sample result:**

```
ID   Name    TableName
1    Name1   creatures
2    Name2   creatures
1    Name3   items
1    Name5   anothertable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hard code in the sql as below

```
(SELECT ID, Name,'creatures' as TableName FROM `creatures` WHERE ... )
UNION
(SELECT ID, Name,'items' as TableName FROM `items` ...)
UNION
( ... FROM `anothertable` ... )
```